# Security using jsonp

Tags: api, web-services, json, client

I'm writing an app that will make available a set of api functions that require cross site scripting to work.  I'll be utilizing jsonp which will allow other developers to consume these services for their web applications.

- What security concerns should I consider to protect my server data?
- What security concerns should other developers take when consuming my services via jsonp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you still have a chance, you should take a look at CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing). It is the W3C specification that is intended to replace the JSONP wrapping workaround, and it went into working draft as recent as April 3, 2012.

So my answer to you, in regards to security, is that you should [look at CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

[Here is the W3C Working Draft Security Considerations link, regarding CORS security and the 'replacement' of JSONP.](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#security)